# A better way of showing the set of all $m\times n$ matrix is an $R$ module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $m$ and $n$ be any positive integers. For any $a\in R$ and $A=(a_{ij})\in M_{m\times n}(R)$ define $aA=(aa_{ij})$. Then prove that $M_{m\times n}(R)$ is an $R$-module.

Edited: Take $a_{ij}\in R$. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Not really, but do take care of notation. You are considering $m\times n$-matrices with coefficients in what?

Comment: Then there is no reason to expect it to be an $R$-module as the action you define then requires an action on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: So, how do I show that it is an $R$ module any hint?

Comment: If it really is meant to be real matrices then you simply don't, because it might not be. What is more likely is that these are meant to be matrices with entries in the ring $R$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: what if the entries are in the ring $R$?

Comment: Then you look at the actual action you have had defined. In your attempt you seem to be assuming that $r$ ans $s$ and natural numbers for some reason.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I don't how to start. Any help?

Comment: It follows directly by using that $R$ is a ring and how matrix addition is defined. Do you see how to show that $R$ is an $R$-module?

Comment: Is $a(A + B) = aA + aB$? Is $(a+b)A = aA + bA$? Does $1_RA = A$? Is it true that $a(bA) = (ab)A$? Inquiring readers want to know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $R$ is a ring $(R,+)$ is an abelian group. Hence $(M_{m\times n}(R),+)$ is an abelian group where "$+$" the usual matrix addition.

Now, let $a,b\in R$ and $(a_{ij}),(b_{ij})\in M_{m\times n}(R)$. Let's check the three module axioms and we are done

(i)
\begin{align}
a((a_{ij})+(b_{ij}))&=a((a_{ij}+b_{ij})) 
 =(a(a_{ij}+b_{ij}))\\
&=((aa_{ij}+ab_{ij})) 
 =((aa_{ij})+(ab_{ij}))\\
&=(aa_{ij})+(ab_{ij})=a(a_{ij})+a(b_{ij})
\end{align}
(ii) 
\begin{align}
(a+b)(a_{ij}) &=((a+b)a_{ij})
 =(aa_{ij}+ba_{ij})\\
&=(aa_{ij})+(ba_{ij}) 
 =a(a_{ij})+b(a_{ij})\\
\end{align}
(iii)
\begin{align}
(ab)(a_{ij}) =((ab)a_{ij})=(a(ba_{ij}))=a(ba_{ij})=a(b(a_{ij}))
\end{align}